# Faster image recognising?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pyautogui

```
CastImage = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('Cast.png', region=(426, 579, 643, 676))
PullImage = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('pull.png', region=(426, 579, 643, 676)) 
stopper = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('stopper.png')
ensure = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('ensure.png', region=(154, 88,  624, 132))
```

I want this part of code to be faster because searching for photos on the screen consumes too much time (I even specified the region which to search in for this photos but it haven't helped). Maybe I should use an other library? How can I locate images on the screen faster?

Here's my full code:

```
import pyautogui as pag
import time


def cast():
    flag = True
    while flag:
        CastImage = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('Cast.png', region=(426, 579, 643, 676))
        print('searching for cast image')
        if CastImage is not None:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            click = pag.click(CastImage)
            print('clicking cast image')
            flag = False


def pull():
    flag = True
    while flag:
        PullImage = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('pull.png', region=(426, 579, 643, 676))
        print('searching for pull image')
        if PullImage is not None:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            click1 = pag.click(PullImage)
            print('clicking pull image')
            flag = False


def strength():
    flag = True
    stopper = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('stopper.png')
    ensure = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('ensure.png', region=(154, 88,  624, 132)) # ensures that this is right window(with game)
    while flag:
        print('Searching for strengthBAR')
        strengthgreen = pag.locateOnScreen('strength.png', region=(355, 304, 774, 528))
        if strengthgreen is None and ensure is not None:
            clickPull = pag.mouseDown(534, 634) # FIXED VALUE
            print('PULLING')
        if stopper is not None:
            flag = False
            print('Stopping strength function')


while True:
    cast()
    pull()
    strength()
```

Comment: Which “process of recognising photos” are you talking about? You show code with `sleep` commands and `click` commands. Is this somehow related to the recognition? You will have a better chance of a useful answer if you clearly explain what your code does, what the purpose is, and which bit is slow and needs to be faster.

Comment: `CastImage = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('Cast.png', region=(426, 579, 643, 676))
PullImage = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('pull.png', region=(426, 579, 643, 676))
stopper = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('stopper.png')
ensure = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('ensure.png', region=(154, 88,  624, 132))`

I want this to be faster because the program is 'searching' for photo on screen for too much time (Thats why i specified region, to at least minimally improve timing)

Comment: Then please explain it clearly in, the question itself, that the specific code that you need help with is the `pag.locateCenterOnScreen` function). Also, try to remove all unnecessary code such as printing, sleeping and the loops (as you said yourself they were unnecessary). In other words, create a [mcve].

Comment: I did that with opencv a little while ago, it was quite fast, see "find_in_screen" there : https://github.com/lc-thomas/clash_royale_bot/blob/master/bot.py